# Any shortcut for typescript constructor with named parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
import { Model } from "../../../lib/db/Model";

export enum EUserRole {
  admin,
  teacher,
  user,
}

export class UserModel extends Model {
  name: string;
  phoneNo: number;
  role: EUserRole;
  createdAt: Date;
  constructor({
    name,
    phoneNo,
    role,
    createdAt,
  }: {
    name: string;
    phoneNo: number;
    role: EUserRole;
    createdAt: Date;
  }) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    this.role = role;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
  }
}
```

Is there any shortcut way to write the above code?And does typescript has the concept called named constructor?

*ignore - It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` and bleed all properties to `this` as property names are same

```js
import { Model } from "../../../lib/db/Model";

export enum EUserRole {
  admin,
  teacher,
  user,
}

export interface IUserModel {
  name: string;
  phoneNo: number;
  role: EUserRole;
  createdAt: Date;
}

export class UserModel extends Model {
  name: string;
  phoneNo: number;
  role: EUserRole;
  createdAt: Date;
  constructor(userModel: IUserModel) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, userModel)
  }
}
```